# Dynamically populate values in Listbox in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks in Advance.

I have a listbox(say lstbox) in "Sheet1" and Range of values in column A in "Sheet2". 
The listbox should populate values dynamically from Column A in Sheet2. I have tried with named reference also but it is not working. 
Any help on this is very appreciated

Comment: show some of your macro code for more precise help please...

Comment: pls "record" a macro where you change the input-range and then try to change it byyour needs. if you still ned help, let us know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a dynamic name range by going in to **"Formulas"** Tab in which click on **"Name Manager"** and insert on **"New"** button.

Enter the Name for range (I have given the name as ***TestValue***) and then use Following Formula at "**Refers To area**" as  "**=OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!$A:$A),1)**" without Quotation Mark.

After that go to sheet 1 and add ListBox from ActiveX control. Right click on it go to "**View Code**".

Erase every thing in it and type the below code.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_GotFocus()
    ListBox1.ListFillRange = "TestValue"
End Sub
```

That's it. When you click on list box it will populate it.